# Set Fields value as

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

Using info path

Using manage rules, I am trying to copy the value of field value, into a separate field.

My issue is that when a value is chosen from the drop down, the field is populated correctly. However, the value of the other field is displaying as the ID. Just to confirm, neither drop down holds the ID number.
Both fields are drop downs. And the drop downs are sharepoint lists.

I have used this option previously, on different forms, without issue. The only difference now is that the sharepoint lists, used for the dropdowns, were uploaded from Access tables

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Value** of the drop-down list box.

Right click the drop-down list box > Drop-Down List Box Properties > Change the **Value** as you want.

[image]